# Finding the points nearest to a given x?

Tags: python, algorithm, function

I need to interpolate a linear function and I can't use `numpy` or `scipy`.

I'm given this data points `((0,10), (1,4), (2,3), (3,5), (4,12))` and a point on `x = 2.8. the data points is polyline (linear between 2 coordinates)

of course I need to use the closest `x`-points from the data for `2.8`. which is from `(2,3)` and `(3,5)` because `2.8` lies between the `2` and `3`.

How do I make a function to find this closest points?

Comment: First, try to think about how you can distinguish the pair `(2,3)` from the pair `(1,4)` or `(0,10)`.  What makes them different.  Then think about how you might go about describing this in an algorithm.

Comment: Note: [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] are version *specific* tags. You **should not** use both. If you don't care for the python version then use **only** the [tag:python] tag. If you care for a specific version then use [tag:python] *and* the tag for that particular version. Avoid using multiple version-specific tags and remember to always use the [tag:python].

Comment: Hi Bakuriu, im thinking that its determine by the distance. because (2,3) the 2 is closer to 2.8 than the 1 or 0 from (1,4) or (0,10) respectively.

Comment: The problem is not really clear... Are these "uncertain"  data points that you must fit with a single straight line (=> you need to perform a linear fit) or they are the vertices of a polyline?

Comment: Hi Matteo, these data points are the vertices of polyline. so between the 2 coordinates is always linear. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def closest(points, x):
    return sorted(points, key=lambda p: abs(p[0] - x))[:2]

>>> points = ((0,10), (1,4), (2,3), (3,5), (4,12))
>>> x = 2.8
>>> closest(points, x)
[(3, 5), (2, 3)]
```

This can also be written without using lambda function (but `x` have to be global then):

```
def mySortKey(p):
    return abs(p[0] - x) 

def closest(points):
    return sorted(points, key = mySortKey)[:2]
```

Comment: Hi Delgan, thanks for the reply. yes (3,5) is the closest point but i need 2 closets point such that 2.8 lies between them, so it would be (2,3) and (3,5)

Comment: @YusufNing Sorry, I misunderstood. I fixed my answer, so it returns the two closest points.

Comment: Hi @Delgan, can you explain to me what key=lambda does? sorry, im new to python.

Comment: @YusufNing In python, you can use lambda to declare an anonymous function. So `lambda p: abs(p[0] - x)` returns `abs(p[0] - x)` if you call it with the parameter `p`. `key` is a named parameter the sorted function takes to specify the sort order.

Comment: and it is possible not use the lambda function. like make it more generic? something like

Comment: def closest(points, x):
    return sorted(points, def f(z): abs(z[0] - x)) [:2]

Comment: @YusufNing Python doesn't allow inline functions other than lambdas. You could declare your sort function (`key`) like `def mySortKey(p): \n\t return abs(p[0] - x)` and pass it to sorted: `sorted(points, key = mySortKey)`. Mind the `\n\t`, this should be a newline and a tab character!

Comment: @YusufNing The `key` optional parameter was introduced to speed up sorting: it is a function which is applied to every items and the returning result is used to sort the list. In this case, `abs(p[0] - x)` give the distance between an item and the `x` value, this distance is used to sort the list, so item with a smaller distance come first. See [the doc](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).

Comment: @Cipher thanks, that works. my instructor told me that this is actually suppose to be a helper function. so that i should construct it with loop so that the function can handle any data points and any point on x.

Comment: why cant i change "key" into another variable like z?

Comment: @YusufNing What do yo umean by "changing key into z"? `key` is the argument name to which you give a function `f()`. While sorting, there is `f(p)` for each `p` in the list. The function can take only one argument. This is why using `lambda` is actually the more generic solution.

Comment: im just confuse why the argument name "key" cant be change to other name like "z", or "function" something like that

Comment: @YusufNing Because `key` is an optional argument for [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted). If you call `sorted()` without providing `key`, the function will perform a default sort. This is how Python works, the function can not recognize parameters if you rename them.

Comment: I see so in a way, "key" is like built in then?

Comment: @Delgan, would i be able to get your email address? appreciate it

Comment: It is not exactly a built-in... While defining a new function like `def f(a, z=0, blabla="toto")`, `z` and `blabla` are optional parameters, this means if I can call `f(9)` then `f()` will use its default values, but I can also say `f(9, z=78)` and then `f()` will use the new `z` value. And If I call `f(9, r=7)` this will raises an error because there is no such named optional argument. So if you call `sorted()` without specifying `key`, `sorted()` will use it default function (which is a regular sort). And if the argument you are passing is not `key` or `reverse`, it will raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by eliminating the pairs which do not bound the target point.

```
x = 2.8
given = [(0,10), (1,4), (2,3), (3,5), (4,12)]
fewer = [(a,b) for a,b in given if a <= x and b >= x]
```

Then you might want to choose the smallest range which bounds the points.

```
result = min(fewer, key = lambda l: l[1]-l[0])
```

You can improve on this method by possibly combining the steps, but this solution breaks the problem down into smaller components.

I'll leave it to you to make this into a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the distance of chosen points.

1) Search for the minimun distance X value (left and right).

2) Search each points corresponding with X_MIN_LEFT and X_MIN_RIGHT. At the same time you can check the distance with Y and find the minimum Y distance.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, the only things that matter are the first values of your 2-tuples?

This is a very simple approach:

```
def getNearest(x, points) :
    smaller = [point for point in points if point[0] <= x]
    greater = [point for point in points if point[0] >= x]
    smallest = max(sorted(smaller))
    greatest = min(sorted(greater))
    return smallest, greatest

points = ((0,10), (1,4), (2,3), (3,5), (4,12))
x = 2.8

pointA, pointB = getNearest(x, points)
```

`pointA` and `pointB` are the nearest lower and upper points to your `x`.

Comment: Hi BioGeek and Cipher. yes thats correct, the only thing that matters is the first value in the tuple. thanks